# Deprecation warning in while connecting to mongodb Atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

> Server running in development mode on port 4500 (node:18135)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: Could
>   not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common
>   reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that
>   isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas
>   cluster's IP whitelist:
>   https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
>       at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/home/waseem/Documents/devcamper_api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:823:32)
>       at Mongoose.connect (/home/waseem/Documents/devcamper_api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:333:15)
>       at connectDB (/home/waseem/Documents/devcamper_api/config/db.js:4:30)
>       at Object. (/home/waseem/Documents/devcamper_api/server.js:11:1)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:839:10)
>       at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 (node:18135) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:18135) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

enter code here

```
  {
      const mongoose = require('mongoose');

    const connectDB = async () => {
        const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
            useNewUrlParser:true,
            useCreateIndex:true,
            useFindAndModify:false,
            useUnifiedTopology: true 
        });

    console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`);

    };
    module.exports = connectDB;

    }
```

Comment: The main issue is mentioned here: "Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/"

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure that your application can reach your MongoDB Atlas environment. To ensure connectivity with Atlas, you must whitelist the inbound network access from your application environment to MongoDB Atlas by whitelisting public IP addresses if you are using AWS. So try `Universal IP address i.e. 0.0.0.0/0` if you want to access your Mongo from anywhere.

You can add IP address by going to `Network Access` and then click `ADD IP ADDRESS`.

Refere this image:
[image]

visit for more info: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/setup-cluster-security/#add-ip-addresses-to-the-whitelist

Comment: thank you very much.. to know what the error is exactly it is better to mention anything globally instead of try catch methods...
const server = app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`));

//Handle unhandled promise rejections 

process.on('unhandledRejection', (err,promise) => {
 console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`);

 //close server & exit process

 server.close(() => process.exit(1));